# How to use scapy to send GTPv2 message?

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

I'm using scapy (https://github.com/secdev/scapy) to send gtpv2 Echo Request message as below:

```
from scapy.contrib.gtp_v2 import GTPV2EchoRequest as GTPV2EchoRequest
from scapy.contrib.gtp_v2 import IE_RecoveryRestart as IE_RecoveryRestart
from scapy.contrib.gtp_v2 import GTPV2Command as GTPV2Command
ie = IE_RecoveryRestart(ietype='Recovery Restart', restart_counter=17, CR_flag=0, instance=0)
gtp = IP(src="10.64.13.28", dst="10.71.33.131")/UDP(sport=2123, dport=2123) / GTPHeader(seq=12345) / GTPV2EchoRequest() / GTPV2Command() / ie
ans, unans = sr1(gtp,timeout=2)
```

But, I see malformed packet on wireshark.:

[wireshark-snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb49U.png)

Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Following code worked:

```
from scapy.contrib.gtp_v2 import GTPHeader as GTPHeader
from scapy.contrib.gtp_v2 import GTPV2EchoRequest as GTPV2EchoRequest
from scapy.contrib.gtp_v2 import IE_RecoveryRestart as IE_RecoveryRestart
ie = IE_RecoveryRestart(ietype='Recovery Restart', length=1, restart_counter=17, CR_flag=0, instance=0)
gtp = Ether()/IP(dst="10.15.11.93")/UDP(sport=2123, dport=2123) / GTPHeader(seq=12345, length=9, P=0) / GTPV2EchoRequest(IE_list=[ie])
ans, unans = srp1(gtp,timeout=2,iface='eth0')
```